# Center of an ideal of a $C^\ast$-algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, ring-theory, ideals, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra and $I$ is an ideal of $A$, then $Z(I)=Z(A)\cap I$? where Z(.) is the center.

I have read in a paper https://doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rnaa133 that it is well known fact that $Z(I)=Z(A)\cap I$ for a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ and $I$ two sided closed ideal of $A$.

I have done that $Z(A)\cap I$ trivially contained in $Z(I)$. But I am getting no idea how to do converse containment. Is there any idea or hint how to do it. Is some property of $C^\ast$-algebra will be used to prove that?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in Z(I)$. Let $\{u_k\}$ be an approximate unit for $I$. If $a\in A$, then
$$ax = \lim_k a (u_k x) = \lim_k (au_k)x = \lim_k x(au_k) = \lim_k (xa)u_k = xa$$
so $x\in Z(A)$.

Comment: Ok so here basically we are using approximate unit of $C^\ast$-algebra. So in any Banach algebra which has ideal with approximate unit satisfy this relation. So a counter example can be made if ideal does not have approximate unit. May you give such example.